# How do I synchronize time data in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, time

I have multiple data sets from different sources of varying length. One txt file has time in seconds , other one has in 10hz ( varying at times) so my data is messy.
I am trying to compare these kind of data sets , but I need a smart way to sync the timeseries first along with adjacent columns of data.
Any help would be appreciated.

Here are two example data sets:

### Data Set 1

```
Time              data 1         data 2      data 3
12:19:00 PM       0.06875        0.1625      0
12:19:01 PM       0.06875        0.1625      0
12:19:02 PM       0.06875        0.1625      0
12:19:05 PM       0.06875        0.1625      0
12:20:06 PM       0.06875        0.15625     0
12:20:00 PM       0.06875        0.1625      0.02300251
```

size of data one is 600, 10

### Data Set 2

Data set 2 looks similar with more columns and different start and end time with different frequency so size of data 2  is `[1000, 40]`

```
Time            data 4    data 5    data 6      data 7     ...
12:00:00 PM     0.45875   0.1625    0
12:19:01 PM     0.06875   0.1625    0
12:19:01 PM     0.06875   0.1625    0
12:19:01 PM     0.06875   0.1625    0
12:20:00 PM     0.06875   0.15625   0
12:20:00 PM     0.06875   0.1625    0.02300251
...
1.00.20 PM      ...       ...       ...
```

sorry if my question is not clear.

I am looking to generate a third time axis based on the shorter time axis.
so for this case I have to average the second file into 2 sec intervals ( taking into account missing data)
Objective is to compare data 1 and data 2 from data set 1 and data set 2 at the same time stamps

Size of file1 is not equal to size of file 2

Comment: Hi. This question is very vague and cannot be properly answered, unless you share more details about the exact structure of your data and clarify what you imagine the "synced" output would be.

Comment: I put the sample data, I am looking for a function like vlookup in excel in matlab

Comment: yes its time, with different frequency and missing in middle

Comment: You should explain a little more clearly what you're end goal is here.  Are you trying to match samples from Data Set 1 to Data Set 2 using timestamps?

Comment: @KronoS:  I edited the question to explain better what the end goal is. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for comparing the two sets of data is to time sync it.

```
x1=dlmread('C:\folder\yourfile1.txt'); 
x2=dlmread('C:\folder\yourfile2.txt');

t1 = x1(:,1);
tsr1=timeseries(x1,t1);
t2 = x2(:,1);
tsr2=timeseries(x2,t2);

% Sync 1 and 2
[new_ts12_1 new_ts12_2] = synchronize(tsr1,tsr2,'Uniform','Interval',1)
```

You can decide how you want to interpolate the data; the default is linear

Comment: Thank you, how do I deal with duplicate time stamps?

Comment: are time stamps identical or you are truncating them. use long precession and check this

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to interpolate; you can use `interp1` for your case.
Use like so:

```
new_data = interp1(times, [data1 data2 data3 ...], new_times)
```

your `times` need not be sorted. `new_times` is then the (equally-spaced) times you want values on.

This results in linear interpolation. You could do

```
new_data = interp1(times, [data1 data2 data3 ...], new_times, 'cubic')
```

to use a cubic interpolant. See `help interp1` for more information.

Note that `new_data` will be `size(new_times) x size([data1 data2 data3 ...])`.

**EDIT**:

So, for your case, this is how you'd use it:

```
% Your data sets
dataset_1 = {...
    '12:19:00 PM       0.06875        0.1625      0'
    '12:19:01 PM       0.06875        0.1625      0'
    '12:19:02 PM       0.06875        0.1625      0'
    '12:19:05 PM       0.06875        0.1625      0'
    '12:20:06 PM       0.06875        0.15625     0'
    '12:20:00 PM       0.06875        0.1625      0.02300251'
    };

dataset_2 = {...
    '12:00:00 PM     0.45875   0.1625    0'
    '12:19:01 PM     0.06875   0.1625    0'
    '12:19:01 PM     0.06875   0.1625    0'
    '12:19:01 PM     0.06875   0.1625    0'
    '12:20:00 PM     0.06875   0.15625   0'
    '12:20:00 PM     0.06875   0.1625    0.02300251'
    };

% (This step is probably not needed (or should be changed) if you're
% reading from file)
dataset_1 = cellfun(@(x) textscan(x, '%s%s%f%f%f'), dataset_1, 'UniformOutput', false);
dataset_2 = cellfun(@(x) textscan(x, '%s%s%f%f%f'), dataset_2, 'UniformOutput', false);

% Extract & convert times
times_1 = cellfun(@(x) datenum( [x{1}{1} x{2}{1}] ), dataset_1);
times_2 = cellfun(@(x) datenum( [x{1}{1} x{2}{1}] ), dataset_2);

% Prepare the data for interpolation 
dataset_1 = cellfun(@(x) [x{3:end}], dataset_1, 'UniformOutput', false);
dataset_1 = cell2mat(dataset_1);

dataset_2 = cellfun(@(x) [x{3:end}], dataset_2, 'UniformOutput', false);
dataset_2 = cell2mat(dataset_2);

[times_12, inds] = unique([times_1; times_2]); % (must use distrinct times)
dataset_12 = [dataset_1; dataset_2];
dataset_12 = dataset_12(inds,:);               % (and corresponding data) 

% Create a new times vector, that increases in regular steps
% (100 for this example)
times_3 = linspace(min(times_12), max(times_12), 100); 

% Now interpolate
dataset_3 = interp1(times_12, dataset_12, times_3)
```

Comment: this method does not work for me as new vector has to be same length as the original vector.  Like I mentioned, what I am trying is to create a third data set with all the rows ( including the ones missing in my data set 2 ) and then eventually averaging them to match the time period of data set 1.

Comment: @user2494472: dig deeper -- you can use a linearly increasing time vector as `new_times`, thus creating your third data set.

Comment: used >>new_data = interp1(data1(:,1), [data1 data2], new_times); it shows argument errors

Comment: @ Rody : sorry I am new in this. I  got rid of new_times variable as I do not know how to predefine it.  I do not understand the document for interp1. When I just use  new_data = interp1(data1(:,1), [data2 data1]);  my ans does not make sense. I mostly get NaN, but I have many matching time stamps. And all the columns give me interpolation valu based on column 1 only . I need whole data set

Comment: ,Thank you, but I think you did not understand the question. IF you look at my two files, they are not of same size. What I am trying is get all the columns from data 1 and data 2 ,So my new file will have 6 columns if my  file1  has 2 columns and file2 has 4 columns

Comment: @user2494472: OK, I see now. I think I've given you enough to go from, it's a really easy step to go from what I have to what you want. More than willing to help out, but not going to clean your house :)

Comment: @ Rody OK if u say so!!will post my different solution later with a different approach